# What is the difference between PathPrefix() and Handle(pathString, ...) in gorilla/mux?

Tags: go, gorilla

I noticed that there are two ways to specify a path in the [`gorilla/mux` router](https://github.com/gorilla/mux):

```
r.PathPrefix("/api").Handler(APIHandler)
```

And:

```
r.Handle("/api", APIHandler)
```

What is the difference?

Also, I don't understand the difference between a router and a route in the context of `gorilla/mux`.

`PathPrefix()` returns a route, which has a `Handler()` method. However, we cannot call `Handler()` on a router, we must call `Handle()`.

Look at the following example:

```
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir+"/public")))
```

I am trying to serve static files from a public directory. The above expression works without any problem. My HTML and JavaScript are served as expected. However, once I add something to the path, e.g.

```
r.PathPrefix("/home").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir+"/public")))
```

Then I am getting 404, not found error on `localhost:<port>/home`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Router vs. Route

`Router` is a container within which you can register multiple `Route` instances. The `Route` interface is largely replicated on `Router` to enable easy creation of `Route` instances in the `Router`.

Note that all of the `Router` methods that have the same name as a `Route` method are wrappers around [`Router.NewRoute()`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/cb4698366aa625048f3b815af6a0dea8aef9280a/mux.go#L267), which returns a new `Route` registered to the `Router` instance.

For comparison, when you call such methods on an existing `Route` instance, it returns the same instance for chaining method calls.

#### PathPrefix() vs. Path()

When you specify a path using `PathPrefix()` it has an implicit wildcard at the end.

A quote from [the overview section of the documentation](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#overview):

> Note that the path provided to PathPrefix() represents a "wildcard": calling PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(...) means that the handler will be passed any request that matches "/static/*".

On the other hand, when you specify a path using `Path()`, there's no such implied wildcard suffix.

#### Router.Handle() vs. Router.Path().Handler()

[`Router.Handle()` is a shortcut for, and therefore equivalent to, executing `Router.Path()` followed by a call to `Route.Handler()` on the returned `Route`.](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/cb4698366aa625048f3b815af6a0dea8aef9280a/mux.go#L276)

Note that this is **not the same** as calling `Router.PrefixPath()` followed by a call to `Route.Handler`, since `Router.Handle()` does not provide the wildcard suffix.

#### Serving files from a path with a prefix

For your last example, try changing:

```
r.PathPrefix("/home").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir+"/public")))
```

To:

```
r.PathPrefix("/home/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/home/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir+"/public"))))
```

Otherwise, it's trying to serve files from `dir + "/public" + "/home/"`

An example of this is in [the documentation, halfway through the overview](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#overview).